# Firefox won't open (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: firefox, 22.04

I'm currently trying to run Firefox via terminal and keep getting this error:

```
error: cannot communicate with server: Post "http://localhost/v2/snapctl": dial unix /run/snapd-snap.socket: connect: connection refused
ERROR: not connected to the gnome-3-38-2004 content interface.
```

And when I try opening it via taskbar, it loads and doesn't even open.

Is there a reason on why this happens? Is there a way to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I found [this discussion](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-d-error-cannot-communicate-with-server-connection-refused/6093/34). In post #35 there are some solutions: restart the `snap` daemon in several ways. Please try those.

Comment: @Jos Thanks! I'll have a look.

Comment: @Jos Apparently every step there didn't seem to work, I don't know if it's because the discussion was outdated, but it just didn't seem to work.

Comment: @ARMathieu, I'm not sure about the error message, but the snap version of Firefox won't open for me with my Nvidia graphics card, Wayland, and the nouveau driver. I can either switch to the proprietary Nvidia driver, or use Xorg rather than Wayland. I've been doing the latter. To test with Xorg, you can log out, then using the gear icon in the lower-right corner, switch to Ubuntu on Xorg for the login, then see if you can launch Firefox from Terminal and the Launch Bar.

Answer (score 2):

Execute these commands:

```
$ sudo snap install gnome-3-38-2004
$ snap connect firefox:gnome-3-38-2004 gnome-3-38-2004:gnome-3-38-2004
```

Then re-try to launch Firefox.